# Want to put comma separated values from 1 column to another or in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, database, function

Here, All the Data is coming data from api.
 Consider, there is a task which can assigned to one or more than one users - 
TASK_TABLE is given below: 
TASK_ID,TASK_NAME,ASSIGNED_TO,CREATED_DATE,...etc. 
 Now the ASSIGNED_TO column has the data (Mention below).
From this column I want only the comma separated User names like - Bat Man,Super Man ,Spider Man. 
Column->

 ASSIGNED_TO:

```
 [  
      { 
        "id":"bf2b9698-3557-422c-8116-27f57e763e50",
        "profileUrl":"/products/people/profile.aspx?user=bat.man",
        "displayName":"bat man"
      },  
      {
        "id":"1f0acef8-5193-4daf-b42c-72c9cec8c284",
        "profileUrl":"/products/people/profile.aspx?user=super.man",
        "displayName":"super man"
      },  
      {
        "id":"217eacdd-ff80-4c2c-8e72-755a3e5bba44",
        "profileUrl":"/products/people/profile.aspx?user=spider.man",
        "displayName":"spider man"
      }
    ]
```

Actual_Table

```
id   name        assigned_to
1   Task1       (refer the above data)
```

Table I want

```
id   name       assigned_to 
1   Task1       Bat Man,Super Man ,Spider Man
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [assigned_to] [varchar](max) NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.[Test] (
    [id]
    ,[name]
    ,[assigned_to]
    )
VALUES (
    1
    ,'task1'
    ,'[{"id":"bf2b9698-3557-422c-8116-27f57e763e50","profileUrl":"/products/people/profile.aspx?user=bat.man","displayName":"bat man"}
       ,{"id":"1f0acef8-5193-4daf-b42c-72c9cec8c284","profileUrl":"/products/people/profile.aspx?user=super.man","displayName":"super man"}
       ,{"id":"217eacdd-ff80-4c2c-8e72-755a3e5bba44","profileUrl":"/products/people/profile.aspx?user=spider.man","displayName":"spider man"}]'
    )
GO
```

Comment: Can you expand on this? I'd suggest outlining one or two scenarios, and include which values should end up in the table columns. Please include table and column names.

Comment: The column data should be- Bat Man,Super Man ,Spider Man rest of all is garbage

Comment: I'm afraid I can't based on the question; there isn't enough to go on. Try to add as much detail as possible. If all the detail you have is what's in your question, try working with a classmate to help figure out the requirements.

Comment: Please edit (append) your original question rather than adding comments.  Comments are hard to read.

Comment: Done.Question Modified.

Comment: Your question is still really vague. I will provide you with a basic idea of what you need to do. Assuming the format of all the data is the same you can use a combination of substring and charindex.

Comment: If possible normalize your database and don't store a comma separated list...this is a red flag that you need a many to many table

Comment: Please add an example of what you would like as a result.

Comment: Please again Refer the above question I have added example and with SQL Query to create table and insert data.

Comment: Sean Lange YOu got me. But I dont know how to write function for this ,Can you please help me in this ?

Comment: So you want to extract JSON data inside SQL Server? You said this comes from an API. Why not do this in the language that calls the API before storing it in SQL Server?

Comment: Zoff Dino You are right, The data is already parsed by json deeper to 3rd level. Can't we do this by Function?